# Android - Why my code doesn't work - FindViewById?

Tags: java, android

I'm new at Android programming, and I have a question here, my code doesn't work, but according to my book, it's supposed to...

This is a noob question, I think, but it's important for me to learn why it doesn't work and how to solve it.

My problem is that `findViewById()` doesn't return any value and the button that I'm trying to access is not available for my app.

This is my code:

```
private Button mButtontrue=null;
(more code...);
mButtontrue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_true);
mButtontrue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

And... this is my R class...

```
public static final class id {
(more code...)
public static final int button_true=0x7f05003d;}
```

And... this is my xml

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/button_true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_true"/>
```

But the fact is that mButtontrue (and the "false" button also) is still null, and i don't know why? (or what should i do?, or maybe what am i doing wrong?, or what's missing in my code?)

Comment: the button belongs to which layout and which layout do you inflate in activity??

Comment: And where is this code, `mButtontrue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_true);`? Is it inside of a method? If so, which one?

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks, you solved my problem with your suggestion, i realized that i was not inflating the correct layout :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on user @Ragunandhan, i solved my problem, because i was not inflating the correct layout. My code was OK, with exception of this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary);

    mButtontrue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_true);
```

And it should be

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButtontrue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_true);
```

Note that i have just changed a word (secondary --> main) in the layout, because i have made a mistake creating the secondary layout (-_-)'.

Thanks everyone that tried to help me solve this problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this (R.id.button_true) from within the activity class? If not you will need to pass the context.

And have you also tried:

```
this.FindViewById
```

You may also want to check if your XML file has saved since modifying it and run a clean on the project :)

Comment: `this.FindViewById` should be `this.findViewById`. this refers to current context which is Activity. But that is not the cause of `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure what the parent layout of that button is. If you are using that button under "AlertDialog", "PromptDialog", "Adapters", "Sliding Drawer" or something like which layout is inflate to Main layout, you have to use layout inflater for your button.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View view = li.inflat(R.layout.your_main_layout, null);

   mButtontrue = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_true);
```

Hope these help!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `findViewById()`?

It seems that you are not calling it, and therefore your listener is `null`

Try this:

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {

Button mButtontrue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    mButtontrue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_true);

    mButtontrue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

}

}
```